# Flutter - Provider working for Web app but when I run on Android it breaks?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, web, provider

I am creating a cross platform flutter app and started developing on the Web version. I have used provider throughout to pass various pieces of data around my app and thus far it works well.

However, when I run my app on Android, the same provider I have used to pull data from Firestore doesn't register any values. When I run on web, I get 2 when I print the length of my list of values whereas on Android, I get 0.

I appreciate there isn't a great deal of information here, but i'm wondering if anyone else has experienced the same issue? And if so, how did you resolve it? Thanks.

UPDATE - added code

Here is how I access the stream from firestore:

```
class OurDatabase {
  final CollectionReference customCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myCollection');

  Stream<List<CustomClass>> get customitems {
    return customCollection.snapshots().map(
          (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs
              .map(
                (document) => CustomClass.fromFirestore(document),
              )
              .toList(),
        );
  }
```

Here is my main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<List<CustomClass>>.value(
          value: OurDatabase().customitems,
          initialData: <CustomClass>[],
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(theme: OurTheme().buildTheme(), home: OurHomePage()),
    ),
  );
}
```

I then access the custom list here:

```
    class OurHeadlineList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<CustomClass> items =
        Provider.of<List<CustomClass>>(context);
    print(items .length);
    return Container();
        }
  }
```

I have swapped out provider for a stream builder and that works - I guess the problem lies with provider?

Like I mentioned previously, when I run on Chrome, the provider works perfectly. But when I run on Android emulator, it doesn't pick up any of the values. I am able to log into firebase through both platforms which confuses me even more. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide code exemple of what you tried ?

Comment: Hi i've added some code into the original question